# Cant play Dropbox file url in AVPlayer

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have a dropbox url

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/plr89to8f6pukts/M04_Video%20Ad%20Formulas%20and%20Templates_6_Weekly%20Q%26A%20Webinar%20%28Thursday%29.mp4?raw=1

It is playing in `AVPlayerViewController`, but doesn't play for custom `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerLayer`.

I have tried to change the host to https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com, but I get the same result.

Is there a way to play dropbox url with `AVPlayer`?

Comment: From the docs: AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem are nonvisual objects meaning that on their own are unable to present an asset’s video on screen. You have two primary approaches you can use to present your video content on screen:

Comment: AVKit: The best way to present your video content is by using the AVKit framework’s AVPlayerViewController class in iOS and tvOS or the AVPlayerView class in macOS. These classes present the video content, along with playback controls and other media features giving you a full-featured playback experience

Comment: AVPlayerLayer: If you are building a custom interface for your player, you use a Core Animation CALayer subclass provided by AVFoundation called AVPlayerLayer. The player layer can be set as a view’s backing layer or can be added directly to the layer hierarchy. Unlike AVPlayerView and AVPlayerViewController, a player layer doesn’t present any playback controls, but simply presents the visual content on screen. It is up to you to build the playback transport controls to play, pause, and seek through the media.

Comment: yes I know that, that's why I use AVPlayerLayer, problem is not in video, it doesn't even play sound.
I can't use AVPlayerViewController, I need custom player.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that?